# What is i run docker run jenkins/jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

My question is like what if i run
`docker run jenkins/jenkins`
without specifying port details then will it run and if it run then on which port it will run? on default?

Answer (score 0):

The Jenkins container will start and will be accessible within the Docker environment. (Container to Container communication) But you will not be able to access it via the Host machine. If you want to access the container from the host machine you have to bind the Jenkins port 8080 of the container to TCP port X of the host machine. You can use `-p 8080:8080` option for this.